# Parse Python Identifier

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I need to determine if a string represents a valid python identifier. Since python 3 identifiers support [obscure unicode functionality](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), and python syntax might change across releases, I decided to avoid manual parsing. Unfortunately my attempts at utilizing python's internal interfaces don't seem to work:

I. function [compile](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#compile)

```
>>> string = "a = 5; b "
>>> test = "{} = 5"
>>> compile(test.format(string), "<string>", "exec")
<code object <module> at 0xb71b4d90, file "<string>", line 1>
```

Clearly `test` can't force compile to use ast.Name as the root of the AST.

Next I attempt using the modules `ast` and `parser`. These modules are intended to derive a string, rather than determining if a string matches a particular derivation, but I figure they might be helpful anyway.

II. module [ast](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html)

```
>>> a=ast.Module(body=[ast.Expr(value=ast.Name(id='1a', ctx=ast.Load()))])
>>> af = ast.fix_missing_locations(a)
>>> c = compile(af, "<string>", "exec")
>>> exec(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '1a' is not defined
```

OK, clearly Name isn't parsing '1a' for correctness. Perhaps this step happens earlier, in the parse phase.

III. module [parser](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/parser.html)

```
>>> p = parser.suite("a")
>>> t = parser.st2tuple(p)
>>> t
(257, (268, (269, (270, (271, (272, (302, (306, (307, (308, (309, (312, (313, (314, (315, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (1, 'a')))))))))))))))))), (4, ''))), (4, ''), (0, ''))
>>> 
>>> t = (257, (268, (269, (270, (271, (272, (302, (306, (307, (308, (309, (312, (313, (314, (315, (316, (317, (318, (319, (320, (1, '1a')))))))))))))))))), (4, ''))), (4, ''), (0, ''))
>>> p = parser.sequence2st(t)
>>> c = parser.compilest(p)
>>> exec(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<syntax-tree>", line 0, in <module>
NameError: name '1a' is not defined
```

OK, still not being checked... why? Quick check of python's [full grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/grammar.html) shows that NAME is not defined. If these checks are performed by the bytecode compiler, shouldn't `1a` have been caught?

I'm starting to suspect python exposes no functionality towards this goal. I'm also curious why some attempts failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to parse, just [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html), and -- if you care -- test if the returned `NAME` is a keyword

Example, partly adapted from the linked documentation:

```
>>> import tokenize
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> from keyword import iskeyword
>>> s = "def twoπ(a,b):"
>>> g = tokenize.tokenize(BytesIO(s.encode("utf-8")).readline)
>>> for toktype, tokval, st, end, _ in g:
...   if toktype == tokenize.NAME and iskeyword(tokval):
...     print ("KEYWORD ", tokval)
...   else:
...     print(toktype, tokval)
... 
56 utf-8
KEYWORD  def
1 twoπ
52 (
1 a
52 ,
1 b
52 )
52 :
0
```

You'll always get an ENCODING (56) token at the beginning of the input, and an ENDMARKER (0) at the end.

Comment: This is a nice approach but it appears you need to add a check for reserved words separately using `keyword.iskeyword` as `def`, `for`, etc tokenize as `NAME`. Not sure if there are other edge cases.

Comment: Good point. If you care about keywords, you have to test that. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I agree, this is a good approach which also explains why neither `ast` nor `parser` worked - identifiers are tokenized and validated before parsing. I find this surprising: python's lexer must encode some state/grammar in order to discriminate valid input, something normally relegated to parsers. Anyway while the `tokenize` module doesn't expose python internals (unlike `ast` and `parser` it reimplements the tokenizer in pure python), it is certainly a more stable approach than using the `dis` module, which carries a big fat warning: "[No guarantees]..[bytecode varies across VMs and releases]"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you were going with your `compile` example, but if you `compile` *just* the potential identifer for `eval`, it exposes what is going on.

```
>>> dis(compile("1", "<string>", "eval"))

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              3 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis(compile("a", "<string>", "eval"))

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              3 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis(compile("1a", "<string>", "eval"))

  File "<string>", line 1
    1a
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

>>> dis(compile("你好", "<string>", "eval"))

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (你好)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

It would require more testing before using for real (for edge cases), but getting a `LOAD_NAME` opcode back is indicative. Failure states can include both an exception and getting a different opcode so you have to check for both.

Comment: The compile example attempts to validate `string` as an identifier by enforcing a subtree of python's grammar through assignment. The example also demonstrates how futile this approach is: suffers from something akin to code injection. You example does the same by ensuring the bytecode matches a certain pattern. While a good idea, unfortunately the `dis` interface is too unstable for my taste.

Comment: `dis` is just to show you - you would use `co_code` and `opcodes` to find whether `LOAD_NAME` is present.

Comment: Although, a string like `(a)` could still be a problem, so never mind.